# Preload database in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin

Im getting an error on Database (The name Database does not exist in the current context), which namespace should i use to import it?
(following http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_5_using_data_in_an_app/)

```
if (!File.Exists (Database.DatabaseFilePath))
    File.Copy (seedFile, Database.DatabaseFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is a typo in the docs.  If you look at the solution for the Advanced project that is linked in the article, DatabaseFilePath is just a static field on a helper class that contains the path to the database.

In iOS, you would build the path using something like this:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mydbfile.sqlite");

if (!File.Exists (dbPath))
    File.Copy (seedFile, dbPath);
```